# Splice together two tables based on timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two Postgresql tables that detail discrete events corresponding to their subject.

Say I have Table A with 3 rows with timestamps (t1, t4, t6) and I have Table B with 4 rows with timestamps (t0, t2, t3, t7, t8).

I want to create a view that shows each record in table B joined with their respective record in Table B such that a row in Table A with timestamp t_i joins with the record in Table B with timestamp directly <= t_i.

For ex, the Table A row at t4 is joined with the Table B row at t3.

If you want to think about it in symbols, see these two tables, as well as the merged VIEW.

(timestamps)

```
Table A: |      |   |

Table B:/    / /     / /  ->

VIEW:   /|   / /|   |/ /
```

Each "|" symbol takes the information of the preceding "/" symbol.

Is this viable with a SQL query?

Thanks!

Comment: How many rows do you expect are in the view using your example?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some real [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) (not just some strange symbols) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

The symbols are not helping much, but if I understood right this may be the way:

```
WITH tableA as 
(
Select 'a1' aid, getdate()-1 A_Date union all
Select 'a4',getdate()-4 union all
Select 'a6',getdate()-6
)
,tableB as
(
Select 'b0' bid,getdate() b_date union all
Select 'b2' ,getdate()-2 union all
Select 'b3',getdate()-3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b7',getdate()-7 union all
Select 'b8',getdate()-8 
)
, j as (
Select * ,row_number() over(partition by aid order by b_date desc) r# 
from tablea
join tableb on b_date<=a_date
)
Select * from j where r# =1
```